# How to return data updated on my vuejs component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, vue.js

I would like to test my component Vuejs.
I use avoriaz, jsdom, mocha and chai.

```
<template>
<div id="test-event" class="test-event">
<button id="button" v-on:click="plusClick" v-bind:value="click_count">{{click_count + " elements"}}
</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        click_count: 0
    },

methods: {
        plusClick(event) {
            console.log("element = ", this.click_count)
            return this.click_count = Number(event.target.value) + Number(1);
        },
       get_click_count() {
            console.log(" => ", this.click_count);
            return this.click_count;
        },

watch : {
        click_count: function(element) {
            console.log("element = ", element);
        }
    }
</script>
```

My unit test

```
it('render button be called ', function() {

    const wrapper = mount(Bar);    
    expect(wrapper.contains('#test-event')).to.equal(true);  //ok
    var test_event = wrapper.find('#test-event');            //ok
    expect(test_event[0].contains('button')).to.equal(true); //ok
    var button_test = test_event[0].find('button')[0];       //ok

    button_test.simulate('click');  // element = 0
    button_test.simulate('click');  // element = 1

    console.log( wrapper.data().click_count );     // 0
    console.log( wrapper.methods.get_click_count() ): 
    // error wrapper.methods.get_click_count() is not a function
    console.log( wrapper.methods.get_click_count ): // undefined
    button_test.simulate('click'); // element = 3
    button_test.simulate('click'); // element = 4

});
```

I would like to retrieve the value of click_count updated but... how can i catch this value ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Vue.js, I would try:

`wrapper.get_click_count()` to call the real method,

`wrapper.$data.click_count` to get the value click_count:

Answer (score 0):

`wrapper.vm.get_click_count` will call the method.

`wrapper.vm.click_count` or `wrapper.data().click_count` will retrieve the data.

There is also a [.methods() method](https://eddyerburgh.gitbooks.io/avoriaz/content/api/mount/methods.html). Although there are problems when calling methods that use `this`.